# Match does not work

Tags: r, match

I was trying to match a numeric to a vector, as following:

```
t <- seq(-4,4,length=81)

tifl.e <--1.5
tifc.e <--0.5
tifr.e <-0.5
tifl.m <--1.6
tifc.m <--0.4
tifr.m <-0.8

match( c(tifl.e, tifc.e, tifr.e), t)
[1] 26 36 46
match( c(tifl.m, tifc.m, tifr.m), t)
[1] NA NA NA
```

I also tried the code, but it gave the same results.

```
tifl.cut <-c(-1.5,-1.6)
tifc.cut <-c(-0.5,-0.4)
tifr.cut <-c(0.5,0.8)

match( c(tifl.cut[1], tifc.cut[1], tifr.cut[1]), t)
[1] 26 36 46
match( c(tifl.cut[2], tifc.cut[2], tifr.cut[2]), t)
[1] NA NA NA
```

Meanwhile, I tried similar syntax by using %in%, which produced the exact same results.

So what is the problem in the syntax? How should I fix it?

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Floating point error:  `t[25] == tifl.m` returns `FALSE` so `match` and `%in% will also.  You could write your own version of match that does "fuzzy" matching using the `all.equal` function instead!

Comment: I think if you are going to title a question **"function XXX Does Not Work"** it might be best to _really_ be sure that it is an issue with the function and not the user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to deal with floating point errors is to use `all.equal`. Here is a custom function for applying `match` to numerics and accounting for the possibility of floating point errors:

```
match.numeric <- function(x, table) {
   are.equal <- function(x, y) isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))
   match.one <- function(x, table)
      match(TRUE, vapply(table, are.equal, logical(1L), x = x))
   vapply(x, match.one, integer(1L), table)
}

match.numeric(c(tifl.e, tifc.e, tifr.e), t)
# [1] 26 36 46
match.numeric(c(tifl.m, tifc.m, tifr.m), t)
# [1] 25 37 49
```

Comment: Points for demonstrating the `isTRUE(all.equal(.))` combo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really want `findInterval` instead of `match`:

```
 findInterval( c(tifl.e, tifc.e, tifr.e), t)
#[1] 26 36 46
 tifl.m <--1.6
 tifc.m <--0.4
 tifr.m <-0.8
 findInterval( c(tifl.m, tifc.m, tifr.m), t)
#[1] 24 36 48
```

If you want to have tolerance factor then just subtract a "fuzz":

```
findInterval( c(tifl.m, tifc.m, tifr.m)- 1e-10, t)
#[1] 24 36 48
```

Comment: Depending on the sign of the floating point error, this will be either right or wrong by `1`. Also, it will always return a result even when the first element is not a member of `t`, while `match` would return `NA`.

Comment: I generally add a `-Inf` on the left and an `Inf` on the right and so avoid the need to add 1. The intervals are closed on the left (which I generally prefer) and is different than the default `cut` behavior.

Comment: I was not talking about the end points. Think about what `findInterval(1.5, c(1, 2))` and `match(1.5, c(1, 2))` both give.